# How to merge multiple DataFrames and accumulate values for duplicated keys?

Tags: pandas

The request is to merge multiple DataFrames with duplicated "key" and accumulate the value associated with the key to a "master" DataFrame.

Is there a Pandas way to achieve the goal? Beside iterate every row and find the value based on the key OR using `df.duplicated('ID', keep = False` to find all duplicated keys and then adding the values to the "master" DataFrame.

My attempt was

```
pd.concat(dfs).duplicated('ID', keep = False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `sum`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('ID', as_index=False)['Value'].sum()
```